# Truncate html text in django

Tags: html, django, text, replace, truncation

In django we can truncate text using Truncator class as

```
from django.utils.text import Truncator
s = "<div>Please truncate this</div>"
Truncator(s).words(2, html=True)
```

This will  return with ellipsis so let's replace ellipsis with something else

```
truncate = "read more %(truncated_text)s"
Truncator(s).words(2, html=True,truncate=truncate)
```

This returns `<div>Please truncateread more </div>`

```
 truncate = "%(truncated_text)s read more" 
 Truncator(s).words(2, html=True,truncate=truncate)
```

this returns `<div>Please truncate read more</div>`

But I would like to get  `read more <div>Please truncate</div>`

This can be done by checking length of truncated text, is there any **smart way** to do this?

Edit:
If it's not possible can we get this `<div>Please truncate</div>read more`

Answer (score 0):

The Truncator class always appends the `truncate` to the end of a string.
So, I think best way is to compare truncated string and original and add "read more " if it's needed

Truncator class source code.
https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/utils/text.py#L224

Comment: As I already mentioned, this can be done using comparison, I am looking for some other way around. Problem is with Truncator it appends inside text instead of adding at last.  I have update question for this part.

Comment: You can not do this using django Truncator.